# BaseGameUtils Gamehelper SingIn failed

Tags: android, google-play-services

**LogCat** for the `GameHelper` tag:

```
06-21 02:39:44.898: D/GameHelper(14315): GameHelper: Debug log enabled.
06-21 02:39:44.898: D/GameHelper(14315): GameHelper: Setup: requested clients: 1
06-21 02:41:59.378: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: Debug log enabled.
06-21 02:41:59.378: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: Setup: requested clients: 1
06-21 02:41:59.473: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: resetting attempt count.
06-21 02:41:59.543: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: Starting USER-INITIATED sign-in flow.
06-21 02:41:59.543: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.
06-21 02:41:59.543: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: Starting connection.
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: Connection failure:
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper:    - code: SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(4)
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper:    - resolvable: true
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper:    - details: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{41c25018: android.os.BinderProxy@41c4a710}}
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: WILL resolve because user initiated sign-in.
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: resolving problem...
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{41c25018: android.os.BinderProxy@41c4a710}}
06-21 02:42:00.268: D/GameHelper(19740): GameHelper: Result has resolution. Starting it.
```

Answer (score 0):

In absence of much context I am guessing that your problem lies with needing to handle the result from the activity that's started in the last log line. That activity handles the login process and returns a result to your own Activity. You need to handle that result yourself. There is an example in the Google Play Games tutorial: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

Search the tutorial page for onActivityResult - you need to override this method in your own Activity as shown in the tutorial example.

Some additional background: when you connect via GoogleApiClient to establish a connection to Google Play Games Services, that API attempts to authenticate the player. When the player is not logged in to the Games Services yet, then the GameHelper starts a new Activity to handle the login process. Once this activity returns, you need to handle the result from the log in.